# Which step do I need to set up the mail server using postfix?

Tags: postfix, email-server

I have to setup mail server with domain abc.com and virtual user in Mysql database !
Now I have my DNS MX record point successfully to my mail server !
I google around ... too many tutorial and article set up mail in different way _ _" : some one use Packet manager, some one build from source and then apply patch for their installation, and the authentication style made me headache!

I really want to build from source for the sake of clarify 
and here is my question list that I'm  now worrying !
Which are mail server component ? Step to setup ?

SMTP : postfix

IMAP/POP3 : dovecot or courier ?

MUA : evolution

How to intergrate mysql and postfix for virtual user ? How to manage virtual user mail (add user, delete user, quota ....) ?

What kind of authentication do I need ? how to use them ?
How to use antivirus ?

How to test and troubleshoot mail server ? Application for monitoring mail server ?

What is the big picture of the mail server and its component ?

Answer (score 2):

First, unsing the pre-packaged binaries is not a bad idea. Or do you like patching by hand and recompiling every time a security flaw is found? Let the package managers do that for you.

Second, make a list of features you really need to implement and what could be needed in the future. Read through the documentation of the software of your choice to make sure it meets the criteria.

postfix + Dovecot + virtual users + MySQL backend is a fairly common setup - again, read the documentation and/or grab one of the too many articles you found on the web already. I would start with the [ISP style mail server](http://workaround.org/articles/ispmail-etch/)-HOWTO or [this Blog post](http://www.opensourcehowto.org/how-to/mysql/mysql-users-postfixadmin-postfix-dovecot--squirrelmail-with-userprefs-stored-in-mysql.html).

Comment: The "blog post" link goes to a couple of jewelry posts. I would suggest it gets removed.

Answer (score 1):

[opensourcehowto.org](http://www.opensourcehowto.org/how-to/mysql/mysql-users-postfixadmin-postfix-dovecot--squirrelmail-with-userprefs-stored-in-mysql.html)

[howtoforge.com ubuntu](http://www.howtoforge.com/virtual-users-domains-postfix-courier-mysql-squirrelmail-ubuntu9.04)

[hottoforge.com centos](http://www.howtoforge.com/virtual-users-domains-postfix-courier-mysql-squirrelmail-centos-5.3-x86_64)